# Symfony - How to call the Service Container object from form events?

Tags: forms, symfony, events, service

How to call the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) object from form events?

I created a form where the webmaster can create books. I want to create a [Sylius](http://sylius.org/) Product when an Book is created through this form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class'=>'block1')
        ))
        ->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            array($this, 'onPreSetData')
        )
    ;
}

public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $book = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $productFactory = $this->container->get('sylius.factory.product');

}
```

For that purpose, I need to reach 'sylius.factory.product' service as explained there: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/products/products.html

```
$productFactory = $this->container->get('sylius.factory.product');
```

I can access it from any Controller, but unfortunately I can't access it from the BookType class I defined.

Here is the error returned by Symfony when I try to access it from the buildForm() or onPreSetData() function:

> Notice: Undefined property: FrontendBundle\Form\BookType::$container

Comment: make `BookType` as service and pass `@sylius.factory.product` as an argument to it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the service, to the form, via the options

Answer (score 0):

Actually this process is very well explained in Symfony Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html

So I updated the way I was calling my form like that:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm($form, $item, array(  //WITH SYLIUS
    'sylius_factory_product' => $this->get('sylius.factory.product')
));
```

Instead:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm($form, $item); //WIHOUT SYLIUS
```

Plus, I adapted the configureOptions function like that:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FrontendBundle\Entity\Book'
        ))
        ->setRequired('sylius_factory_product')
    ;
}
```

Instead:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FrontendBundle\Entity\Book'
        ))
    ;
}
```

You can now access your service in the buildForm function like so:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $productFactory = $options['sylius_factory_product'];
    //...
}
```

Comment: What made you chose this approach over simply defining the the form type as a service and then not worrying about having to inject the factory into the options?

Comment: I don't know this approach. If I define my BookType class as a service, will I be able to access all factory/services objects? Can you explain?

Comment: I should also point out the actually creating a product from inside a form type might not be the best design.  If it works for you then okay but products and forms are really two different things.